# Zend form: secure way store entry ID when editing?

Tags: security, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm new to the Zend Framework and I have a problem to create an edit form with the Zend_Form.

My problem is that I need to store the entry ID during editing, I've seen some examples that are using a hidden form field, but a hidden field can be manipulated by a user.

So: how can I set a form field which gets populated by `$form->populate($data);` and is available after submiting the request but is not editabel/visible to the user in any way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there's really a point in trying to hide the value.

Consider the following:

- To display the correct editor form, you need the ID of the object that is to be edited.
- Before allowing the user to edit a certain ID, you would check if the user can edit it or not.

Thus, if you put the ID in the form, it shouldn't really matter:

- When you POST the edit form, you should *again* check that the user can still edit the ID.
- If the user changes the hidden ID, it doesn't really matter. They could still go and edit the other ID by finding it on the site. (This is assuming your check didn't  tell you the user does not have access)

Answer (score 0):

what kind of data you wanna hide?
data should be in post or get.if you dont put your data in your form,then you will have to use GET which is less secure than POST.
If you have some data and you dont want the user to see those data,then you should not put those data in a form.you can store and retrieve hidden data using form`s submitted values.lets suppose your hidden field is user`s password.you dont need to send password back to the client when client is editing the form.you can manipulate password in your controller according to the user`s submitted first name and last name.
If you still insist, you may wanna try encrypting data using ZF and echo ing your value and setting encrypted data into a hidden form element.

Comment: Why ist get post more secure than get? please explain, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Form generates an HTML form element with the form elements you specify. So its element capabilities are narrowed to a simple HTML form.

The hidden form element is used to pass those data that the user is not supposed to enter by hand. But as you yourself said it, there is no guaranty it could not be tampered. so no security is provided by using a hidden form value.

Most of times you'd better use server side values (like stored in sessions) to reference to values that are to be protected from user.

I suggest you keep the ID in a session value, and then you could use the session key in the hidden form field. this way the user can not change the target ID. However you are not able to use the $form->populate($values) on this in one step. you would have to set the target value with other steps:

1. fetch data from the session
2. set the form element value with the fetched data